# Using if/elif/else for a "switch" in python

Tags: python

While using the following code:

```
url = None
print("For 'The Survey of Cornwall,' press 1")
print("For 'The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes,' press 2")
print("For 'Pride and Prejudice,' press 3")
n = input("Which do you choose?")
if n==1:
    url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/9878/pg9878.txt' #cornwall
    print("cornwall")
elif n==2:
    url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1661/pg1661.txt' #holmes
    print("holmes)
elif n==3:
    url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt' #pap
    print("PaP")
else:
    print("That was not one of the choices")
```

I'm only getting the "else" case returned, why might that be??

Comment: also, there's a quote missing after `"holmes`. Just letting you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input()` returns a string in py3x. So, you need to convert it to `int` first.

```
n = int(input("Which do you choose?"))
```

Demo:

```
>>> '1' == 1
False
>>> int('1') == 1
True
```

Comment: cool, thanks guys, gonna pick this one as the answer when the timer expires!

Comment: Also, if you just want a string (which you can then convert to an int), you should be using `raw_input`.  `input` is unsafe, as it runs `eval` on what the user types.

Comment: @sapi OP is usong py3x not py2x, and `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in py3x.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - my mistake.  I didn't notice that from the OP.

Comment: @sapi - actually, I don't think the OP ever actually said, but if he/she were running Py2, then the code would have run okay as-is, as the Py2 behavior of `input` was to also do an implicit `eval` on the string before returning it.

Answer (score 3):

`input()` returns a string, but you are comparing it to integers.  You can convert the result from input to an integer with the `int()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the input with int()
`n = input("Which do you choose?")` should be `n = int(input("Which do you choose?"))` 
This is due to the fact that input returns strings for all input since it should almost always work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using Python 3, in which `input` behaves like `raw_input` did in Python 2, that is, it returns the input value as a string. In Python, '1' does not equal 1. You'll have to convert the input string to an int using `n = int(n)`, then go through your succession of elifs.

Answer (score 1):

input() returns a string type. So, you need to convert your input into an integer using int(), or else you can compare the inputs to characters instead of integers, like '1', '2'.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers correctly identify the reason you're getting the `else` block in your current code, I want to suggest an alternative implementation that is a bit more "Pythonic". Rather than a bunch of nested `if`/`elif` statements, use a dictionary lookup, which can support arbitrary keys (including perhaps more meaningful ones than integers):

```
book_urls = {'cornwall': 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/9878/pg9878.txt',
             'holmes': 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1661/pg1661.txt',
             'p and p': 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt'}

print("For 'The Survey of Cornwall,' type 'cornwall'")
print("For 'The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes,' type 'holmes'")
print("For 'Pride and Prejudice,' type 'p and p'")

choice = input("Which do you choose?") # no conversion, we want a string!

try:
    url = book_urls[choice]
except KeyError:
    print("That was not one of the choices")
    url = None
```

You could make the whole thing data-driven if you wanted, with the book names and urls being provided as an argument to a function that would ask the user to pick one (without knowing what they were ahead of time).